# How to hide picker view and date picker

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I am using picker view and date picker in table view like
textfield.inputview=pickerview..

I want to hide both views after selecting value I did it by :

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.paymentText.text=[pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    self.picker.hidden=YES;
}
```

it is hiding picker view but when I again select that textfield picker view does not appear again..Could any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a line which fires when tapping on the text field?

```
self.picker.hidden=NO;
```

You can also check out the [SimpleUndo Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleUndo/Introduction/Intro.html) from apple

Comment: //self.picker.hidden=NO;
        paymentText.inputView=picker; I used this but  not working

Answer (score 0):

The better way to handle this kind of customization for text field is to add the date picker when text field editing starts and remove the date picker view when editing the done or user pressed done or cancel button on date picker view.

I have created a [demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PnXT1drJOcxl6RZaA49rZ7WQsiKDX70H/view?usp=drivesdk) which contents the same above mentioned behavior and which also restricted to a minimum and maximum date for picker view.